# Why does not receive FCM notifications on IOS when the app is in background and receive in foreground? Flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app that sends Firebase notifications to all the users at some moment. It is working fine at android but in iOS only works with the app open. If I close the app (or go to main screen for example), it did not receive anything.

I already setted 'priority' : 'high', "content_available" : true and still not working. What can I do to perform it?

If you need some code/info I update the question.

UPDATE: Yes, i'm using onResume

```dart
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(

      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
        print(message['notification']['body']);

      },

      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using onResume in configuration?
You need to add it. Check it out

[image: onResume]

Comment: im not sure but problem is probably that you are using print method, when your program on background it won't show up on console  look at logcat instead

Comment: But in android works perfectly, I don't think this is the problem

Comment: oh i see, nvm then